# How to resolve failed execution reading JSON file to get the first name and last name?

Tags: java, json

I'm getting this error

> Execution failed for task ':Card.main()'. Process 'command 'C:/Program
> Files/Java/jdk-11.0.8/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value
> 1
>
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

```
package people;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class people {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/folder/persons.json")));

        for (Object o : a)
        {
            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;
            String name = (String) person.get("firstname");
            System.out.println(name);
            String number = (String) person.get("lastname");
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

JSON file

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "Oscar",
    "lastname": "Thompson"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Raphael",
    "lastname": "Garcia"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Tom",
    "lastname": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Richard",
    "lastname": "Parson"
  }
]
```

Comment: wich library are you using for json ? I'm trying a replication with json-simple-1.1 but your code won't compile

Comment: Also, can you provide the json file formatted as you have it ? it starts with '[' or 'json file' ?

Comment: implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'

Comment: [
  {
    "firstname": "Oscar",
    "lastname": "Thompson"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Raphael",
    "lastname": "Garcia"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Tom",
    "lastname": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Richard",
    "lastname": "Parson"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Ruth",
    "lastname": "Aniston"
  }]

Comment: I can't import those names you're using with this maven depency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1 :/ I want to help but i can't reproduce, have you got a git repo of this project ?

Comment: Version of jdk ?

Comment: and with this? compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20200518'

Comment: I'm updating my ide rn, let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223810/discussion-between-carlos-batista-and-esotopo21).